# Dark Souls 2 : The Scholar of the First Sin for PS3: DLC content on disc?

Tags: ps3, dark-souls-2, dark-souls-2-sotfs

I was wondering if I could buy the Scholar of First Sin as preowned game.
But before I do it, I want to make sure I have all the content, since these days the "one time use" policy is used by the publishers.

So, for PS3 european version, is the content on disc, or do you have access to it through a PSN code?

Comment: Can't speak for the European version but a US friend bought the PS3 version used and made it into the DLC without needing to redeem a code. Ditto for me on Xbox One (also US).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought the german version of the game and I can say that this version of the game for the PS3 HAS indeed a PSN voucher code for you to use in order to reclaim access to the DLC.
This access is made through some keys. If you do no have this tiny content downloaded in your console, than you get no access to the DLC areas.

I don't know if this applies to other versions of the game, namely in the US. I believe that throughout europe this code version is also used.

As a mather of fact, only a paper cover and a voucher panflet inside are the differences between the normal version, because inside the paper there is a normal version of Dark Souls II: first day retail cover and disc.

Answer (score 1):

Dark Souls 2: Scholar of the First Sin doesn't actually have any DLC... or at least note yet.

> The definitive edition of DARK SOULS™ II. DARK SOULS™ II: Scholar of the First Sin includes all the DARK SOULS™ II content released to-date in one package and much more!

(Quote is from the game's page on Steam)

Areas that were DLC in Dark Souls 2 now have keys hidden somewhere in the world that you have to find to access them.

Comment: Yeah. Thank you for the answer, but that doens't mean the content is really unlocked for me. There can be a PSN code to unlock the extra areas, and the previous owner of the game might have used it.
I really need to know this from someone that has the game.

Comment: the areas ARE PART of SOTFS, you can't remove places from a game. Sunken king, ivory king, old iron king, all these are IN the game. So if you buy a pre owned version you will have these zones. There is no such thing as a PSN code or so :)

Comment: I apreciate your point of view. But there is indeed a PSN code to unlock these areas. With this code, you can then get some keys to unlock these areas. If you do not have this code, then you will not get the keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can purchase it off the PSN, you don't need a "code" to download it.

The "code" comes with the disk, and is included in the price of purchasing the game. Eg, the base game costs $50, and the game with the DLC codes cost $80.

You can go out and buy a pre-owned version of the game, then go on to PSN and purchase the DLC from there, at an additional cost. Though all-in-all it will still be cheaper

Comment: So, that is my problem. I don't want to buy the DLC so I save some money. Is there any difference between buying Dark Souls 2: Scholar of the First Sin pre-owned or new? Because if the game comes with a single-use code to access the DLC, the previous owner of the game might have used it, and for me, it's like buying the normal version of the game.

Comment: I believe Powerlord's answer is the better one for this case. "Dark Souls 2: Scholar of the First Sin" contains all of the DLC from the original game as standard content (on the disc).